# Unauthorized elastic-stack-apm-apm-user user failed to index document metrics-apm indices

Tags: elastic-stack, apm

I upgraded APM-server from 7.17 to 8.10.3 image. Since the upgrade, I am getting error

```
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-10-10T21:34:47.374Z","log.origin":{"file.name":"go-docappender@v0.2.1-0.20230724080315-b714d6181871/appender.go","file.line":325},"message":"failed to index document in 'metrics-apm.app.silicon_edge_cache_refresher-default' (security_exception): action [indices:admin/auto_create] is unauthorized for user [elastic-stack-apm-apm-user] with effective roles [apm_system,eck_apm_user_role_v75,ingest_admin] on indices [metrics-apm.app.silicon_edge_cache_refresher-default], this action is granted by the index privileges [auto_configure,create_index,manage,all]","service.name":"apm-server","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
   {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-10-10T21:34:47.374Z","log.origin":{"file.name":"go-docappender@v0.2.1-0.20230724080315-b714d6181871/appender.go","file.line":325},"message":"failed to index document in 'metrics-apm.app.silicon_edge_cache_refresher-default' (security_exception): action [indices:admin/auto_create] is unauthorized for user [elastic-stack-apm-apm-user] with effective roles [apm_system,eck_apm_user_role_v75,ingest_admin] on indices [metrics-apm.app.silicon_edge_cache_refresher-default], this action is granted by the index privileges [auto_configure,create_index,manage,all]","service.name":"apm-server","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
```

Because of this, my services are not appearing in APM. Can anyone advice on how to solve this?

I tried to manually add the required privileges `[auto_configure,create_index,manage,all]` but the user in question is inbuilt user, I could not update the role. Maybe I am not doing it right?